# Dollar Sign will not echo in form

Tags: php, forms

I have a form with field data that comes from a table row that contains dollar signs($), but the `$` won't echo. I've tried both escaping or replacing, below, but nothing works.

1) `Foreach` method:

```
foreach($prices['current'] as $value)
  {      
    $s = str_replace('$', '&#36;', $value'];
    echo  $s;
}
```

My form field:

```
Current Price: <input type="text" name="current<?=$prices['id']?>" value='<?=$prices['current']?>' />
```

Result: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

2) Using Curly brackets:

```
Current Price: <input type="text" name="current<?=$prices['id']?>" value='<?={$prices['current']}?>' />
```

Comment: How about you just do `value="$<?= $prices['current']; ?>"`

Comment: There should be no issue printing a $ in a string that comes from the database. It's only an issue when you write in a string in double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

garbage in -> garbage out ! it's a 101 rule in coding

Answer (score 0):

You could echo string literal **using single quotes:**

```
<?php

echo 'I give you $1';

?>
```

will print:

I give you $1

Comment: Or just write "I give you \$1";

Answer (score 0):

You're not modifying your array. All you're doing is changing a string, outputting it, and then throwing away the result. Perhaps you want:

```
foreach($prices['current'] as $key => $value) {      
    $prices['current'][$key] =  str_replace('$', '&#36;', $value);
}
```

But given your error, `$prices['current']` is probably **NOT** an array, just the price string, so you'd probably want

```
function quote_dollar($value) {
   return str_replace('$', '&#36;', $value);
}

<input .... value="<?php echo quote_dollar($price['current']); ?>" />
```

Comment: MarcB-Forgot to mention that $prices["current"] is an array. Using your code: 
foreach($prices['current'] as $key => $value) {      
    $prices['current'][$key] =  str_replace('$', '&#36;', $value);
} 

Results : Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Connor Tumbleson. Thank you, your idea of simply adding a $ does work if the entry is entered without the $. However, some rows have more than one amount or a range, example: 500-600. Just adding the $ before the variable results in $500-600.

Answer (score 0):

You have an unnecessary

```
'
```

at the end of:

```
$value'];
```

get rid of the '

Comment: And the `]` should be a `)`